# Change default column name sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with Nodejs, [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). This is following structure of my user model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('user', { 
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isUnique: function (email, done) {
            User.find({ where: { email: email }})
                .done(function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        done(err);
                    }
                    if (user) {
                        done(new Error('Email already registered'));
                    }
                    done();
                });
        }
    }
    },
    profile_image_path: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    active_flag: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    delete_flag: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.account),
        User.hasMany(models.user_has_contact)
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

By default 3 columns are created:

- id
- createdAt
- updatedAt

I don't want `createdAt` & `updatedAt` in this format, what i want is `created_at` and `updated_at`. How to change these default column name???

I have another table `user_has_contact` with following relationship:

```
{
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        UserHasContact.belongsTo(models.user)
      }
    }
  }
```

Its creating `userId` field automatically but again i want it as `user_id`. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sequelize.define('user', ..., {
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
});
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration

```
UserHasContact.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#foreign-keys

Comment: If i'll use `foreignKey: 'user_id'` do i have to create `user_id` column also.

Comment: Not if you let sequelize create the tables (`sequelize.sync`)

Answer (score 20):

you can do it globally by adding this setting in your configuration as below

```
 var config=  {
     "define": {
          "underscored": true
        }
    }

  var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var config=  {
     "define": {
          "underscored": true
        }
    }
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);
```

this code by ashwini jindal work for me